# using meteor's accounts-facebook, i get a url error

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-social-plugins

I set the url for my app as http://localhost:3000
and I get this error

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
my app domain is empty, since fb doesnt let me set it to localhost:3000

I'm totally lost..

Comment: try a test version of the app with site url: http://localhost:3000.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of your Facebook app, you need to add "localhost" as an App Domain, not "localhost:3000". You don't need to include the port with the hostname.

Comment: I tried to do that. I get App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: localhost.....        NOW WHAT?

Comment: Facebook allows you to create a [test version of your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps), which is useful for exactly these types of situations. In this test version, you can configure different URLs. For instance, I have a production, testing, and local version of my app, which all remain separate with different app IDs and configurations.